# Graphs: Minimum Cycle Basis generated by Horton's algorithm is not consistent

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

This is my first post. I've a big doubt regarding **Graphs**, I'm working on a program to generate them using different efficient algorithms, starting from **"Horton"** (1978, 1st polynomial time approach).

Horton states that a **greedy** approach can generate the **Minimal Cycle Basis**:

**1.** For each vertex, generate a Shortest Path Tree based on that vertex and analyze it against all edges to search for cycles. Thus creating a **Cycle Space** of at most mxn cycles (m:n. of edges; n: n. of vertices).

**2.** **Sort** all found cycles by weight in non-increasing order.

**3.** Start adding them one-by-one into a set (MCB), checking if the "candidate" cycle is **linearly independent** with the set (discarding it if doesn't). This, until MCB has "v" cycles *(v = #vertices - #nodes + 1)*.

According to Horton, the resulting Cycle Space ( should contain a MCB (Minimum Cycle Basis). I've found this is true for most cases, but I found a particular one for which the resulting MCB is not consistent (i.e. The Symmetric Difference of the cycles in the MCB do not generate the original graph).

[MCB NOT consistent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DscC.png)
(MCB generated using Horton's algorithm -- the edge (3,5) is not included in any cycle, I guess because its weight is "avoided" by  all Shortest Paths)

[MCB consistent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO18T.png)
(Potential MCB that will cover all edges)

*Can someone explain to me if I got the procedure wrong or is it the graph that doesn't admit a MCB?*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, after Step 1, there must definitely be cycles containing edge $35$. For every pair of vertex $u$ and edge $vw$, the cycle we create consists of the shortest path from $u$ to $v$, the edge $vw$, and the shortest path from $w$ to $u$, assuming that the resulting cycle is simple (the two shortest paths have no vertex in common except for $u$).

In particular, for every edge $vw$, there will be at least one cycle in the Horton set which contains that edge: the shortest cycle containing $vw$. (Just take any other vertex on that cycle as $u$: if the shortest paths $u$ to $v$ and $u$ to $w$ had another vertex $u'$ in common, the cycle starting and stopping at $u'$ would be shorter.)

In your example graph:

[image: example graph]

For edge $35$, if we take $u = 1$ and $vw = 35$, then the cycle we create consists of the edges $(14, 43, 35, 51)$.

Second, at least one cycle containing edge $35$ (or any other given edge) must survive Step 3: the first cycle we consider that includes edge $35$ must be linearly independent from the others.

In this example, after Step 1, I get

- $(12, 25, 51)$ with weight $132$,
- $(14, 45, 51)$ with weight $143$,
- $(12, 23, 34, 41)$ with weight $143$,
- $(21, 14, 45, 52)$ with weight $187$,
- $(14, 43, 35, 51)$ with weight $187$,
- $(21, 14, 43, 35, 52)$ with weight $231$.

We include the first three cycles, which are linearly independent, exclude the fourth cycle (since it's in the span of the first two cycles), include the fifth cycle, and exclude the sixth cycle (since it's in the span of the first and fifth).

Regarding the linear independence of cycles: you need to be careful here, since just using straightforward incidence vectors will not work. You have two options:

1. Check linear independence modulo $2$. Then, if we order the edges of $G$ as $(12, 14, 15, 23, 25, 34, 35, 45)$, the cycle $(12, 25, 51)$ has incidence vector $(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)$, the cycle $(14, 45, 51)$ has incidence vector $(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)$, and the cycle $(21, 14, 45, 52)$ has incidence vector $(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)$. We have $$(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) + (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) \equiv (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1) \pmod 2$$ so these cycles are linearly dependent.
2. Keep track of edge directions, and treat edge $wv$ as the "negative" of edge $vw$. Then, with the same edge order as above, the cycle $(12, 25, 51)$ has incidence vector $(1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)$, the cycle $(14, 45, 51)$ has incidence vector $(0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)$, and the cycle $(21, 14, 45, 52)$ has incidence vector $(-1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1)$. We have $$-(1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) + (0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) = (-1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1)$$ so these cycles are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I summarized the 1st step but I perform it as you mentioned, and I get this **MCB**:

C1={ (0,1) (0,4) (1,4) } w=1.32 C2={ (0,1) (0,3) (1,2) (2,3) } w= 1.43 C3={ (0,3) (0,4) (3,4) } w=1.43 C4={ (0,1) (0,3) (1,4) (3,4) } w=1.87.

But this basis is **wrong** (symmetric difference), as the **(3,5)** edge is missing. I guess the problem is on the **Selection**, cycles that include (3,5) are excluded due to their **heavy weight**:

**C5** = { (1,4) (1,5) (3,4) (3,5) } w=1.87 or **C6** = { (1,2) (1,4) (2,5) (3,4) (3,5) } w=2.31. 

Can you tell why this result?

Comment: Why are you excluding the cycles containing $(3,5)$? As I said, at least one of them **must** be chosen in Step 1 (when considering vertex $1$ together with edge $(3,5)$, for instance) and the first of them considered in Step 3 **must** be linearly independent from the others, and therefore it gets included in the final result.

Comment: After generating **all** cycles in Step1 (including the ones with edge 3-5); I **sort** them by **weight** in Step2. Then I start adding them into the MCB one-by-one (**from lightest to heaviest**) as long as the pass the **"linear-independence test"**, this until the number of required cycles **(v = #edges - #nodes + 1)** is reached. The problem is that that **v** is reached before arriving to the cycles with (3,5)! and so my MCB is already complete... I can't understand why this happens, because I can "force" the algorithm to take a cycle with **(3,5)** before the end.

Comment: I see your problem: you should not be including the cycle with edges $(21, 14, 45, 52)$, because it's a linear combination of cycles $(12, 25, 51)$ and $(14, 45, 51)$, which you've already included. I've edited my answer to explain this.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Oh yes! Cycle **C4** (21,14,45,52) is a span of **C1** and **C2**, in this way **C5** goes straight into a **consistent** MCB (**in theory**). In practice, **C4** should be discarded by the test of **linear-independence** (gauss elimination, proposed by Horton) but C4 results to be linear-independent with **C1** and **C2** (and even **C3** all together), thus making it impossible to discard it! I double-checked the procedure for the cycle's incidence vectors: 
**C1**=1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0; **C2**=1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0; **C4**=1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 
Do u have any idea?

Comment: Linear dependence between cycles is determined by slightly different rules than the ones you're using. Just taking the straightforward incidence vectors, as elements of $\mathbb R^{|E(G)|}$, will not work. I've edited my answer to outline two alternatives.

Comment: I own you a beer! or even better, a whiskey! This explains lot of things to me (all related to linear independence and other MCB algorithms), with me programming 3 different functions for gaussian elimination because thinking they were "bad implemented". Do you have any advice/link/pseudocode/procedure on how to implement the **linear independence modulo 2** for systematic testing? Regarding edge directions there's no problem because my case concerns only undirected graphs. Thank you Misha!

Comment: Checking linear independence modulo 2 is exactly the same as regular linear independence, except easier: you row-reduce, but never have to multiply by scalars, you just add mod 2 (or subtract mod 2) the pivot row to every row that has a $1$ in the same position. (Also, the second version applies to undirected graphs as well. It does not matter which direction of an edge you choose to be the "positive" one and which you choose to be the "negative" one.)

Comment: Everything is working fine now. Thank you very much for your **highly instructive** answers. Now is time to start coding De Pina! :)